# I'm trying really hard to understand how I can add a container with textviews inside my Recyclerview so I could click on it and retrieve the textviews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, containers

I'm trying really very hard to figure out how I can isolate textviews into a container so I can load it into a Recylerview so then later I could simple touch that and retrieve those textviews values and insert them into my editTexts.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVkpM.jpg)

As you can see, this is my current recyclerview and everything you see there "ID: X", "Descrição: X", "Quantidade: X" and "Local: X" are in their own Textviews. The problem is, no matter how I hard I try, I simple cannot isolate them into a Cardview layout so they could be on their own container (the Cardview) so later I could click in this cardview and retrieve those textviews value to insert into my edittexts (hints ID, Descrição, Quantidade, Local).

Here is my XMLs:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/visualizador_recycle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="560dp"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ID"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="ID"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/descricao"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Descrição"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/qtd"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="QTD"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/local"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Local"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cadastrar"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Cadastrar"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alterar"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Alterar"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

row_visualizador.xml (this xml contains the Textview layout that will be inserted into the recyclerview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_visualizador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descricao_visualizador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantidade_visualizador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/local_visualizador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my adapter:

```
package com.example.inventario;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<String> mbanco;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> banco) {

        mbanco = banco;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_visualizador, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.id.setText(mbanco.get(position));

        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mbanco.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView id;
        TextView descricao;
        TextView quantidade;
        TextView local;
        LinearLayout parentLayout;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_visualizador);
            descricao = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descricao_visualizador);
            quantidade = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantidade_visualizador);
            local = itemView.findViewById(R.id.local_visualizador);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.inventario;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> mbanco;
    private String m_Text = "";

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    EditText id, descricao, quantidade, local;
    Button cadastrar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.visualizador_recycle);

        id = findViewById(R.id.ID);
        descricao = findViewById(R.id.descricao);
        quantidade = findViewById(R.id.qtd);
        local = findViewById(R.id.local);

        cadastrar = findViewById(R.id.cadastrar);

        cadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Database db = new Database();

                db.inserir(descricao.getText().toString(), quantidade.getText().toString(), local.getText().toString());

                carregar();

                descricao.setText("");
                quantidade.setText("");
                local.setText("");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Bem cadastrado com sucesso.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

    public void carregar() {

        Database db = new Database();

        mbanco = new ArrayList<>();

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mbanco);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mbanco.addAll(db.carregar());
    }

    public void pesquisar(String descricao, String quantidade, String local) {

        Database db = new Database();

        mbanco = new ArrayList<>();

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mbanco);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mbanco.addAll(db.pesquisar(descricao, quantidade, local));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Database db = new Database();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.carregar:

                carregar();

                return true;

            case R.id.pesquisar:

                AlertDialog.Builder pesquisar = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                pesquisar.setTitle("Pesquisar");
                pesquisar.setMessage("Informe a descrição, quantidade ou local do bem.");
                pesquisar.setCancelable(false);

                EditText editTextPesquisar = new EditText(this);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutPesquisar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                editTextPesquisar.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutPesquisar);

                pesquisar.setView(editTextPesquisar);

                pesquisar.setPositiveButton("Pesquisar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        pesquisar(editTextPesquisar.getText().toString(), editTextPesquisar.getText().toString(), editTextPesquisar.getText().toString());

                    }
                });

                pesquisar.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);

                pesquisar.create().show();

                return true;

            case R.id.deletar:

                AlertDialog.Builder deletar = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                deletar.setTitle("Deletar");
                deletar.setMessage("Informe o ID do bem que deseja excluir do banco de dados.");
                deletar.setCancelable(false);

                EditText editTextID = new EditText(this);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutDeletar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                editTextID.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutDeletar);

                deletar.setView(editTextID);

                deletar.setPositiveButton("Deletar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        db.deletar(editTextID.getText().toString());

                        carregar();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Bem com o ID " + editTextID.getText().toString() + " foi deletado.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                deletar.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);

                deletar.create().show();

                return true;

            default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
}
```

How can I make a layout with the textviews so I could insert that layout with the textviews into my recyclerview so I could add a clicklistener to get the textviews values? Sorry if my code is a mess, It been a very long time since I did something with Android, still using Java... not even Kotlin.

Edit:

I tried something by changing my row_visualizador.xml to be a cardview instead of Linearlayout and this happens:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzmgW.jpg)

here is the xml now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_visualizador"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descricao_visualizador"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantidade_visualizador"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/local_visualizador"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I dont know why this happens, it all weird to me because for me they are in their own containers but still appears like that. I'm used to Python and it so easy to organize everything inside their canvas/frames.

Edit2:

I tried something and this is what happens now:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLKA5.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkNlK.jpg)

Recyclerview has big spaces inbetween textviews for some reason, and I just don't know why this happens really.

My nem row_visualizador.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="712dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_visualizador"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descricao_visualizador"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_visualizador" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantidade_visualizador"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descricao_visualizador" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/local_visualizador"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quantidade_visualizador" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My new Adapter:

```
package com.example.inventario;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<String> mbanco;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> mbanco) {

        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mbanco = mbanco;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_visualizador, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String textId = mbanco.get(position);
        holder.id.setText(textId)
        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mbanco.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView id, descricao, quantidade, local;
        ConstraintLayout parentLayout;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_visualizador);
            descricao = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descricao_visualizador);
            quantidade = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantidade_visualizador);
            local = itemView.findViewById(R.id.local_visualizador);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        }
    }
}
```

My new MainActivity:

```
package com.example.inventario;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> mbanco;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    EditText id, descricao, quantidade, local;
    Button cadastrar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.visualizador_recycle);

        id = findViewById(R.id.ID);
        descricao = findViewById(R.id.descricao);
        quantidade = findViewById(R.id.qtd);
        local = findViewById(R.id.local);

        cadastrar = findViewById(R.id.cadastrar);

        cadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Database db = new Database();

                db.inserir(descricao.getText().toString(), quantidade.getText().toString(), local.getText().toString());

                carregar();

                descricao.setText("");
                quantidade.setText("");
                local.setText("");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Bem cadastrado com sucesso.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

    public void carregar() {

        Database db = new Database();

        mbanco = new ArrayList<>();

        mbanco.addAll(db.carregar());

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.visualizador_recycle);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mbanco);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public void pesquisar(String descricao, String quantidade, String local) {

//        Database db = new Database();
//
//        mbanco = new ArrayList<>();
//
//        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
//        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mbanco);
//        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
//        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
//
//        mbanco.addAll(db.pesquisar(descricao, quantidade, local));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Database db = new Database();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.carregar:

                carregar();

                return true;

            case R.id.pesquisar:

                AlertDialog.Builder pesquisar = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                pesquisar.setTitle("Pesquisar");
                pesquisar.setMessage("Informe a descrição, quantidade ou local do bem.");
                pesquisar.setCancelable(false);

                EditText editTextPesquisar = new EditText(this);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutPesquisar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                editTextPesquisar.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutPesquisar);

                pesquisar.setView(editTextPesquisar);

                pesquisar.setPositiveButton("Pesquisar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        pesquisar(editTextPesquisar.getText().toString(), editTextPesquisar.getText().toString(), editTextPesquisar.getText().toString());

                    }
                });

                pesquisar.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);

                pesquisar.create().show();

                return true;

            case R.id.deletar:

                AlertDialog.Builder deletar = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                deletar.setTitle("Deletar");
                deletar.setMessage("Informe o ID do bem que deseja excluir do banco de dados.");
                deletar.setCancelable(false);

                EditText editTextID = new EditText(this);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutDeletar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                editTextID.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutDeletar);

                deletar.setView(editTextID);

                deletar.setPositiveButton("Deletar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        db.deletar(editTextID.getText().toString());

                        carregar();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Bem com o ID " + editTextID.getText().toString() + " foi deletado.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                deletar.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);

                deletar.create().show();

                return true;

            default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to notify the adapter - or just populate first and then set it to the adapter.

Comment: I see, the problem is I don't know where to start really. I've been looking on google and youtube videos, but people don't see to do what I want. Everything is functional but this in my app.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally did it (not saying it the best answer, but it do work for what I wanted to do)

What I wanted was to get the values of the textView inside my recyclerView so I could then insert them into my editText.

I created a RecyclerViewClickInterface:

```
package com.example.inventario;

public interface RecyclerViewClickInterface {
    void onLongItemClick(int position);
}
```

I also had to recreate my row_visualizador with just one Cardview and one single TextView which would contain the whole string with all the data I want to manipulate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/visualizador"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then on my RecyclerViewAdapter I had to implement the Interface:

```
package com.example.inventario;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<String> banco;
    private RecyclerViewClickInterface recyclerViewClickInterface;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> banco, RecyclerViewClickInterface recyclerViewClickInterface) {

        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.banco = banco;
        this.recyclerViewClickInterface = recyclerViewClickInterface;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_visualizador, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String textId = banco.get(position);
        holder.visualizador.setText(textId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return banco.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView visualizador;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    recyclerViewClickInterface.onLongItemClick(getAdapterPosition());

                    return true;
                }
            });

            visualizador = itemView.findViewById(R.id.visualizador);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally on my MainActivity I implemented the interface and @overrided the onLongClick:

```
package com.example.inventario;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewClickInterface {

    private ArrayList<String> banco;

    RecyclerView RecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter Adapter;

    EditText id, descricao, quantidade, local;
    Button cadastrar, alterar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
                AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.visualizador_recycle);

        id = findViewById(R.id.ID);
        descricao = findViewById(R.id.descricao);
        quantidade = findViewById(R.id.qtd);
        local = findViewById(R.id.local);

        cadastrar = findViewById(R.id.cadastrar);

        alterar = findViewById(R.id.alterar);

    @Override
    public void onLongItemClick(int position) {

        String[] result = ((banco.get(position).replace("ID: ", "").replace("Descrição: ", "").replace("Quantidade: ", "").replace("Local: ", "")).split("\n"));

        id.setText(result[0]);
        descricao.setText(result[1]);
        quantidade.setText(result[2]);
        local.setText(result[3]);
    }
}
```

All I had to do now once implementing the interface on my MainActivity was to manipulate the textView string by replacing the unnecessary and split the string on "\n" regex so I could insert the values into the a Array and finally insert the Array index with the desired value into the desired editText.